# get request with axios and vujes

Tags: vue.js, axios

Good afternoon folks,

How can I  send a `Get` request every time with a search button on my app?

I don`t want to download the whole JSON from the API just only the search results?

Many thanks.

That is my search bar:

```html
     <div id="app">
        <div class="search-wrapper">
        <input type="text" 
               class="search-bar" 
               v-model="search"
               placeholder="Search in the titles"/>
          
      </div>
```

and this is the axios part I have :

```js
      axios
        .get(
          `https://zbeta2.mykuwaitnet.net/backend/en/api/v2/media-center/press-release/?page_size=61&type=5`
        )
        .then((response) => {
          this.items = response.data.results;
        });
```

Comment: if the api has a search param use it, else filter the result by your search field

Comment: "I don`t want to download the whole json from the api just only the search results?" - this isn't how apis work. You have api endpoint with a big load of paged data. If it doesn't provide an endpoint to search for it, there's nothing you can do because doing hundreds of requests to download the whole dataset is totally unreasonable. You need to work with backend devs on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Step 1:*** Create `HTML` template

```
<div class="search-wrapper">
  <form>
    <input
      type="search"
      @input="searchByTitle($event.target.value)"
      class="search-bar"
      v-model="search"
      placeholder="Search by title"
    />
  </form>
</div>
```

***Step 2:*** Add `search by title` `method`

```
searchByTitle(value) {
  clearTimeout(this.debounce);
  this.debounce = setTimeout(() => {
    if (value.length >= 3) {
      this.params = `q=${value}`;
      this.loadPressRelease();
    }
  }, 600);
},
```

We have to make the `REST API` call when there is 3 or more than 3 characters and added `debounce` once we stopped typing then only we are making `REST API` call

***Step 3:*** Added `watch` for when clearing search text

```
watch: {
  search(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (oldVal && !newVal) {
      console.log("morning has broken...");
    }
    if (!newVal) {
      this.clearSearch();
    }
  },
},
```

***Step 4:*** Added searchbar `css` style

```
.search-bar {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.search-bar:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px #b0e0ee;
  border: 2px solid #bebede;
}
.search-box:not(:valid) ~ .close-icon {
  display: none;
}
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-hypatia-htz0z)